# Unable to start activity - No view found for ID

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I am a beginner in programming. I really want to set a default fragment when the app is launched. but in my main activity i have an empty frame layout and i want to replace that with my UserReviewsFragment. When I tried a lot of solutions I found it always says that "No view found".
How can I fix this please.  Thanks in advance.

Actually my UserReviewsFragment works fine it's just in mainactivity that i want to set a default fragment.

My app is having a navigation drawer. 
I have a mainactivity which has a framelayout with an id of main_container

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/userRevs">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_container">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When i try to add or replace a fragment in my framelayout it would have an error saying "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo....  caused by No view found for id.....". I tried a lot of possible solutions but I failed. here's my main activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

UserReviewsFragment userRevs = new UserReviewsFragment();
FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, userRevs ).commit();

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
tvEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
}
```

Inside my UserReviewsFragment is a TabLayout and a Viewpager and inside my viewpager is a recycler view that loads data from firebase.

Comment: I think you should replace or add fragment at the bottom of onCreate() in your activity..

Comment: I do not see any `tvEmail` in your activity_main.xml

Comment: @MiguelIsla i already set a text in my tvEmail

Comment: @MohdSaquib i tried your answer but sad to say the same error :( no view found for id main_container.

Comment: i really had a hard time solving this problem. can you please help me :(. it's been a week already finding solutions to this problem. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone thank you so much for your time reading and sending suggestions on how to solve this problem. I really appreciate it so much. Thank you so much.

And by the way I already solved this problem just now :). I solved the problem in my AndroidManifest.xml because last time in my AndroidManifest.xml my first activity to be launched is my SplashScreenActivity and when I tried to change it into my MainActivity as the first activity to be launched it worked. :) and yiy finally for how many days :( solving this problem.

Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()` method for replacing a fragment. You don't have to initialize a `FragmentTransaction` object with this way.

```
FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, userRevs).commit();
```

Comment: i tried your answer but still no view found for id main_container :(

Answer (score 0):

replace this `tvEmail = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);` from `onCreate();` in your activity to Fragment's `onCreateView();`

Comment: oh i never thought that it is possible to call it in fragment. thank you.